# Значение слов 'при этом,' 'заодно,' 'одновременно'

Tags: значения

В чем разница между этими словами? Кажется, что все они имеют одно и то же значение, но отличаются в том, как они используются. К тому же, можно ли привести несколько примеров?

What's the difference between these words? It seems that all of them have the same meaning but differ from one another in how they are used. Also, could a few examples be provided?

Answer (score 4):

- **Одновременно** simply means **at the same time**.

> Честь имею предупредить, что копию с сего *одновременно* посылаю к барону Бьорингу.

- **Заодно** literally means *for one thing* and is used in the sense of either **on the same side, teamwise** or **at the same time**.

> Выпьют горькое вино
>   На помин души...
>   Жди. И с ними *заодно*
>   Выпить не спеши.

- **При этом** literally means *near to this* and denotes the same as **additionally**.

> *При этом* было сказано как-то даже несколько обидно насчет тоненького мужчины: что он больше ничего, как что-то вроде зубочистки, а не человек.

Comment: what is `for an altogether`? Have you invented this yourself? I cannot find any mentions of such a phrase in dictionaries. Why are you using the article `an` before `altogether`? Is it a noun?

Comment: `при этом` can also have its literal meaning, like при том бордюре лежит мусор, при этом лежит собака. It is important to note such things, I think

Comment: @user907860 Well, that's exactly "near to this (object)". It's quite hard to list all the meanings; SE anyway is not an alternative to a good dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Word "заодно" doesn't always suit the sentence with "при этом"(which might mean "Including (the fact)") and "одновременно" means "at the same time", but can't be used in the beginning of sentence(like "At the same time, I loved another girl"). Here you'd better use "При этом"("При этом я любил другую девушку").

Russian language can be worse than chinese sometimes.